# Storing lots of data in a Python list

Tags: python, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I want a program to generate prime numbers of order up to 10^9.
I am using Sieve of Eratosthenes to implement it in python but I am getting memory error when I try 10^9. It works fine till 10^7.
Here is the code that I am using

```
def prime(n):
    p=[True]*(n+1)
    p[0]=p[1]=False

    for i in range(int(n**0.5)+1):
        if p[i]:
            for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
                p[j] = False

    for i in range(n+1):
        if p[i]:
            yield i
```

I am using windows 10, with 6GB of RAM

Comment: Do you use 64 or 32 bit python? I have run on memory issues myself some time ago and solved in by switching to 64 bit python. In addition: it is not sucha good idea to eat so much memory with python script unless you **have to**

Comment: @MaLiN2223 64 bit.

Comment: You might want to try NumPy arrays

Comment: You can try using Segmented sieve. It's more memory friendly. If I remember correctly there is a clever  python implementation of it using generators.

Comment: If you are using Python 2, then prefer `xrange` to `range` in both loops.

Comment: @Anonta Can you add segmented sieve implementation as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could obtain a huge speedup by just storing the prime numbers themselves, instead of storing true or false on every particular prime number. This would greatly simplify your program and it should also allow you to handle significantly larger values.

## Alternative Approach

Try compiling a list of primes, and then testing only those primes to see if we have any divisors. This is significantly faster and I have no memory issues here, I tried prime(655360002) (which I looked up on wikipedia) without a problem.

```
def prime(n):

    found_primes = []
    for number in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):

        number_is_prime = True

        # The new number can only be divisible by other primes
        for divisor in found_primes:
            if number % divisor == 0:
                number_is_prime = False
                break

        if number_is_prime:
            found_primes.append(number)


    # Now that we have a list of primes, we test our number against them
    for prime in found_primes:
        if n % prime == 0:
            return False


    # IF we tried all primes, then we must be prime
    return True
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  OP, calling `sys.getsizeof(True)` on my system revealed that each boolean is 24 bytes.  That's 24GB for 10^9 booleans... triple your system memory!  As others have suggested, a `numpy` array may be more efficient, but storing these values is going to cripple your system either way.

Comment: I agree. The worst part is *p=[True]*(n+1)*

Comment: Yep, that was the basic problem, the initial step allocates a huge amount of un-needed memory.